# Why the output of cross_validate differ from the hardcode loop when using XGBClassifier?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, xgbclassifier

**Code #1** Pass pipeline with PCA, XGBClassifier steps to scikit-learn cross_validate function

```py
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

import random
random.seed(42)
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

kwargs = {
    'n_jobs': -1,
    'cv': LeaveOneOut(),
    'X': X,
    'y': y
}

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('pca', PCA(1, random_state=42)),
    ('xgbc', XGBClassifier(random_state=42))
])

results = cross_validate(pipe, **kwargs)
print(results['test_score'].mean())
```

**Code #2** Write cross-validation loop hardcode and calculate mean accuracy for exactly same input `X` as *Code #1*

```py
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

import random
random.seed(42)
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

acc = []
for train_idx, test_idx in LeaveOneOut().split(X, y):

    x_train, x_test = X[train_idx], X[test_idx]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_idx], y[test_idx]

    pca = PCA(1, random_state=42)
    pca.fit(x_train)
    x_train = pca.transform(x_train)
    x_test = pca.transform(x_test)

    model = XGBClassifier(random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)

    score = model.score(x_test, y_test)
    acc.append(score)

print(np.mean(acc))
```

Comment: how much do they differ?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan, Result of Code #1 is 0.77 and Code #2 is 0.90.

Comment: Do they differ if you use the same specified metric?

Comment: @hellpanderr, **Metric** is the **same** for both. both are calculating `accuracy`.

Comment: Did you try using the same LeaveOneOut split?

Comment: I didn't exactly understand what you meant, but to clarify, because of setting `random_state` the first code (Code #1) always produces a value of 0.77 and the second one (Code #2) produces 0.90.